# Link posts to pages for breadcrumbs

Tags: php, breadcrumb

Is there a way of linking custom post types to pages.

I am looking to create breadcrumbs for the posts.

The posts are summarised on individual pages e.g. golf, tennis, football etc..

So the Breadcrumb Structure inside the post will be:

Home / Tennis / "Post Title"

When clicking on Tennis - it should lead to the Tennis page I have created which summarises  all tennis events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go and have a look at [template hierarchy for custom post types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates). I believe your custom post type is tennis. So you would make a copy of your theme's `archive.php` template and call it `archive-tennis.php` You can now style that template to your liking.

Just remember, you don't need to add or change any specific code inside your new template to specify your CPT. Wordpress will exactly know it should use `archive-tennis.php` when the custom post type tennis is clicked

Comment: hmm.. this is a nice and neat solution however all posts are under the same custom post type called "calendar" :(

Comment: @JoannaMikalai So if I get you here, tennis is a taxonomy?

Comment: yes. and I use a custom shortcode to display this taxonomy in a page..